# Layer two BitmapImage's in WPF

Tags: wpf, image, layer, bitmapimage

I have two instances of BitmapImage. I would like to layer then on eachother the create a new BitmapImage. How would I do this? (Using C#)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

[How do I tile and overlay images in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359582/how-do-i-tile-and-overlay-images-in-wpf)

Comment: I thought this solved it, but there is one more problem. How do I convert the System.Windows.Media.ImageSource to a BitmapSource (for saving?)

Comment: what about this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201518/convert-system-windows-media-imagesource-to-system-drawing-bitmap