# c# 4.0 how to add layer to an image

Tags: image, c#-4.0, embed, addition, layer

I want to embed some images to another image. This should be done as layers so transparency everything will be kept. Images are png. How can i do that ?

This is like using pngout and adding extra layers.

And the main issue with this is the new layer has to have specific position. For example i have 200x200 main image and 24x22 new layer image. I need to be able to start new layer adding point from lets say top 55px left 25px.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to do this in the GUI, or in the image file itself? PNG doesn't support layers, so you can't do it in the image file.

Comment: thanks for comment. i actually found how to make it. here somebody made just i wanted. i will modify and use it :) http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/BuildWatermarkUtility.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use GSI+ (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1355/Professional-C-Graphics-with-GDI), create a region and draw image on top of one another (using transparency for see through effects).

That said, most people these days use WPF and there is a great Stack Overflow answer posted here to that effect - [How do I tile and overlay images in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359582/how-do-i-tile-and-overlay-images-in-wpf)